# How hide row in table (without display:none)

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablerow

I need to hide row in html table. But I can't use property `display: none`.
Reason - we use `tablesorter` plugin with widgets `staticRow` and `scroller` and when we hide rows with `display: none` we have troubles with incorrect width in header and in table cells.

We discovered that problem is in `display: none`. We tried to use set from several properties for hiding rows

```
tr.hide, tr.hide td {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    padding 0; 
}
```

But this row still have height (not so big as in other cells in table, but still have).

I added 2 examples to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrxr95tg/) (first - with class, which I add above, second - with `display:none`), you can see difference.

UPD: I added

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

And allmost solved my problem, but still exists 1-2 pixels instead of empty row.

UPD2: `border-spacing: 0` for table remove this extra spacing

Comment: Why can't you modify your datasource and reload the table?

Comment: I am not sure if that's what you want, but you can add the attribute  *cellspacing="0"*  for the *table*
With css you can use `#second_table { border-spacing:0;}`

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes thank you guy, it works.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know if you can change my comment into an answer so I will post as answer and you can mark lol

Comment: Could be browser or updates or something, but as of right now, `visibility: hidden` alone works for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that's what you want, but you can add the attribute `cellspacing="0"` for the table. With css you can use.

```
#second_table { border-spacing:0;}
```