# Hide a element but keep its width but make it's height 0 with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would a list of ids of `<tr>` that I want a checkbox to hide and to show when checked and unchecked.  I want to keep the width of the tr intact when visible and hidden.  But I want the height to go to 0 when hidden and then back again when visible.

```
function ShowFutureMS(checkboxMS)
{
    var count = 0;

    for(count = 0; count < listofAddressesWithNoMS.length; count++)
    {
        if(chkShowFutureMaidServices.checked)
        {
            document.getElementById(listofAddressesWithNoMS[count]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(listofAddressesWithNoMS[count]).style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
}
```

My code currently hides the tr and keeps the width the way I want it to.  But when hidden the height remains the same.  How can I modify my code to get the height to 0 when hidden?

Comment: look at `display:block` vs `display:none` (You dont need to be playing with heights)

Comment: But if I use display:none the width becomes all screwed up when I make it visible again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way, just [set height](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_height.asp).

```
    function ShowFutureMS(checkboxMS)
    {
        var count = 0;

        for(count = 0; count < listofAddressesWithNoMS.length; count++)
        {
            if(chkShowFutureMaidServices.checked)
            {
                document.getElementById(listofAddressesWithNoMS[count]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById(listofAddressesWithNoMS[count]).style.height= '0px';
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById(listofAddressesWithNoMS[count]).style.visibility = 'visible';
document.getElementById(listofAddressesWithNoMS[count]).style.height= 'auto';
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: Issue is actually that the other rows do not slide up. Here is an example of using a class to do that. [Taken from answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344198/how-hide-row-in-table-without-displaynone)

HTML:

```
<table style="border-spacing:0">
<tr><td>test data 1</td></tr>
<tr id="hideme"><td>test data 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>test data 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>test data 4</td></tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="document.getElementById('hideme').className = 'hide'" />
<input type="button" value="click me 2" onclick="document.getElementById('hideme').className = ''" />
```

CSS:

```
tr.hide, tr.hide td {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    padding 0; 
    border-spacing: 0
}
```

Comment: I tried something like that.  But all the things that are below are not moved up as expected.  It still appears to be using the heights of each row.

Comment: I am thinking perhaps I need to modify the height of all the tds in each row I want to change?

Comment: Right, this doesn't make the other elements slide back up. See this thread, I tested using a fiddle and it seemed to work well (toggle the class name) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344198/how-hide-row-in-table-without-displaynone

Comment: I added to the answer to show an example using a css class.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use css classes for this purpose. So when you want to hide it, you add a css class which sets the visible property to 'hidden' and the height property to '0px'. When you want to show it,  you remove the class.